# On what basis are javascript files cached?

Tags: javascript, caching, browser

On what basis does javascript files get cached? Say I load a file with the name 'm-script.js' from one site and on another website I use the same name 'm-script.js' but with different contents. Will the browser fetch the new one, or just look at the name and load it from the cache? The urls for both the m-script.js file are different (obviously).
Thanks.

Comment: I also found that the web server adds and [ETag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) which is part of HTTP which is also used for cache validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the url is different the cached copy will not be used. A new request will be made and the new file will be downloaded.

There would be a *huge* security and usability issue with the browser if a Javascript file cached from one website was used on another.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers cache files by their full URI.

This thread( [How to force browser to reload cached CSS/JS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files) ) will help you to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has mentioned it yet, there is a lot more involved in HTTP caching than just the URI. There are various headers that control the process, e.g. `Cache-Control`, `Expires`, `ETag`, `Vary`, and so on. Requesting a different URI is always guaranteed to fetch a new copy, but these headers give more control over how requests to the potentially-cached resource are issued (or not issued, or issued but receive back a 304 Not Modified, or...).

[Here is a detailed document describing the process](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html). You can also google things like "caching expires" or "caching etag" for some more specific resources.