# A funny error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, visual-studio

### Preview of javascript file[Dynamic] does not showing latest code. Why?

---

### Problem

> Visual studio **Preview of `task.js[Dynamic]`**  is showing my old codes

---

### Explanation of the issue

This is my current code in `task.js` file

[image]

But when i run my application and put break point in that screen, now the java-script preview showing my old code. The preview does not show my latest code.

see the below image, this is my old code. i have replaced `$cookieStore.get('userInfo').UserId` instead on `1` in `taskby object` from my old code.

[image]

---

### NOTE

***Please see the yellow markup  in the above images for more proof.***,

---

**What am did** - *I was tried to solve this problem by below ways*

- Pressed Save button more and more times
- Pressed save all button
- So many times i have cleaned the solutions
- also tried build and rebuild the solution.

*But not working*

---

### My Questions :

- Why is this happened?
- And how can we solve this?

---

### Update:

**I got a answer for my second question**

*How can we solve this?* 
**Ans : -**  *I have solve this issue by  restart  `visual studio`*

---

But i don't know, why it's happened. Please tell me guy's, if you know.

---

Comment: How about clearing your browser cache?  We do that quite frequently when we change our javascript that it has become ritualistic.

Comment: Yep, i have cleared the browser cache. the issue was solved by restart the VS. but i don't know why the problem occurred?

Comment: Did you try just clearing cache and not restarting VS?  Does that work?  There is a very similiar post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646447/visual-studio-not-updating-html-javascript-to-server-browser)

Comment: I have tried to clear the browser cache and also hard refreshed the browser. But not working for me. once i restart VS, then solved. Now the problem was solved.**My Question is why this problem happened to me?**

Comment: Javascript files are cached, by default, for performance.  Normally, in a production env, these files aren't constantly changing, so this is perfectly acceptable.  Your development machine would be acting this way as well, so you need to work around it.

Comment: Okay, well can you add this comment to your answer? because that's helps to some others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Reason for the Issue

Javascript files are cached, by default, for performance. Normally, in a production env, these files aren't constantly changing, so this is perfectly acceptable. Your development machine would be acting this way as well, so you need to work around it. [SO post on how JS files are cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810675/on-what-basis-are-javascript-files-cached)

---

## Solution:

In my experience, it is browser cache that causes this and, ritualistically, we just clear the cache before we run the site.  So, in this order:

Change javascript

Save all

[ctrl+shift+f5](http://www.dofactory.com/reference/visual-studio-shortcuts) in Visual Studio

When browser opens, hit f12, the ctrl+r (clear cache) and click yes

When cache clears, hit reload on page.

*If above solutions are does not working, then please restart the visual studio*

Comment: Oh. man. did you fully read my question? i have fixed this by my own. **My Question is why this problem happened to me?**

Comment: Yes, I answered your question and then, for future visitors, gave a way to work through the problem since restarting Visual studio every time you change a JS file isn't a viable solution :) .

Comment: Okay i have edited your answer for some other peoples, please don't remove my edits :) thanks !